# How to solve Crazy JPA Requirements?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In my project am using JPA 1.0 with Hibernate 3.2.x and Tomcat for deployment.

In my project I have used the following query to execute as named query,

```
SELECT smSSTJob.smJob.jobId, smSSTJob.smJob.jobTypeId, smSSTJob.omObject.objectId, 
smSSTJob.omObject.objectName FROM SMSSTJob smSSTJob 
WHERE smSSTJob.smJob.jobTypeId IN (:jobTypeIdList) 
AND smSSTJob.jobStatusId IN (:jobStatusList) 
AND smSSTJob.omObject.objectId NOT IN (SELECT sm.omObject.objectId FROM SMSSTJob sm 
WHERE sm.jobStatusId IN (:unProcessedJobStatusList) 
AND sm.responseReceivedDate &gt; :responseReceivedDate)
AND smSSTJob.priority = :priority 
AND smSSTJob.jobRetries &lt; :maximumJobRetries ORDER BY smSSTJob.smJob.jobId
```

While I deploy my project cause of the above query hibernate thorws the following exception,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.findIntendedAliasedFromElementBasedOnCrazyJPARequirements(FromClause.java:120)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.getFromElement(FromClause.java:107)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:81)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:255)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4253)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.inRhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4161)
```

How do I resolve this exception? Anybody please help me in this context.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked `smJob` in `smSSTJob.smJob.jobTypeId` and `omObject` in `smSSTJob.omObject.objectId` are not `null`?

Comment: The both `smJob` and `omObject` all **foreign key and not null** columns in `smSSTJob`.

Comment: Hibernate 3.2.6 or lower?

Comment: Hibernate version is 3.2.5ga

Comment: `"Its still broken in the latest 3.2.5 GA download."` see [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2159)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2159) in Hibernate, solved in 3.2.6 and later, try to update Hibernate version

Answer (score -2):

could it be that one ")" is missing? To close your subquery.

NOT IN (SELECT sm.omObject.objectId FROM SMSSTJob sm 
WHERE sm.jobStatusId IN (:unProcessedJobStatusList)

Comment: No mistake in that..

NOT IN (SELECT sm.omObject.objectId FROM SMSSTJob sm 
WHERE sm.jobStatusId IN (:unProcessedJobStatusList) 
AND sm.responseReceivedDate &gt; :responseReceivedDate)